# Cut down the waiting time after silence using twilio speech recognition

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

i'm using [Twilio Voice Gather verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to collect [user speech](https://www.twilio.com/speech-recognition) responses to some questions. Is there a way to short the waiting time before calling the action url? Acording to my tests, seems like the default behavior is to wait for more than 6 seconds after silence is detected per each Gather call.

```
var gather = new Gather(input: "speech", action: GetActionUrl(), language: Constants.Language, method: "POST", bargeIn: true, speechTimeout: 3, timeout: 3, partialResultCallback: "/RealTimeVoice", partialResultCallbackMethod: "GET");
gather.Say(promptMessage, language: Constants.Language, voice: Constants.Voice);
response.Gather(gather);
response.Redirect(GetRedirectUrl());
return TwiML(response, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using plain TWIML or a lib?

Comment: i'm using twilio for asp.net mvc , this app is connected to a twilio number using webhooks.
This is the code snippet:

`var gather = new Gather(input: "speech", action: GetActionUrl(), language: Constants.Language, method: "POST", bargeIn: true, speechTimeout: 3, timeout: 3,partialResultCallback: "/RealTimeVoice", partialResultCallbackMethod: "GET");

gather.Say(promptMessage, language: Constants.Language, voice: Constants.Voice);
response.Gather(gather);
response.Redirect(GetRedirectUrl());
return TwiML(response, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: I would try removing `speechTimeout` completely and adjust `timeout` because it should apply to both dtmf and speech. Also, another try `speechTimeout: "auto"` and see how this goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once the timeout has been reached, Twilio needs to use the live recording to generate the final result that is posted to your `action` URL. You currently have the `speechTimeout` set to 3 seconds, so there will be a bit more of a delay after that to get that final result and make the request to your URL.

As Alex has suggested in the comments, you could try `speechTimeout: 'auto'` which is trained to recognise gaps in speech and submit then.

Alternatively, I note that you have set a `partialResultCallback` too. This can be useful for interrupting the call once you have the result you want without waiting for the final result. If you do detect the result you are looking for, you can use the [REST API to redirect the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls) to the next thing you need to do with it instead of waiting.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Seems like there is a sdk bug because the "speechTimeOut" waits for an int type  parameter so i can't set the string 'auto' value :S. I tried removing the timeOut attributes but doing that the wait time increases, and setting a value less than 3  seconds don't give enough time to the user to give answer the questions. The problem is not the time it watis for an answer , the problem is the time it waits after user gives an answer.

Comment: That does sound like an SDK bug, I see you've raised the issue on GitHub, I'll try to get that pushed through as quick as I can. If you remove both timeout attributes then it defaults to 5 seconds, which is why it would take longer.